# How to create a lambda for ostream?

Tags: c++, lambda, operator-overloading, outputstream, ostream

I thought the call of the `operator<<` would generate a two-parameter function call. So, why does this not compile, then?

```
#include <iostream> // ostream
#include <iomanip> // setw, setfill
using std::ostream; using std::setw; using std::setfill;
struct Clock {
    int h_, m_, s_;
    Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    : h_{hours}, m_{minutes}, s_{seconds} {}
    void setClock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
        h_ = hours; m_ = minutes; s_ = seconds;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const Clock& c) {
        auto w2 = [](ostream&os, int f) -> ostream& {
            return os << setw(2) << setfill( '0' ) << f; };
        return os << w2(c.h_) <<':'<<w2(c.m_)<<':'<<w2(c.s_); // ERROR
    }
};
```

The error is (gcc-6)

```
$ g++-6 -std=gnu++1y ...
file.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Clock&)’:
file.cpp:745:33: error: no match for call to ‘(operator<<(std::ostream&, const Clock&)::<lambda(std::ostream&, int)>) (const int&)’
         return os << w2(c.h_) <<':'<<w2(c.m_)<<':'<<w2(c.s_);
                             ^
```

I also tried the call `os << w2(os,c.h_)` but gcc and I agreed that was nonsense. Also I tried the lambda as auto as possible:

```
auto w2 = [](auto&os, auto f) {
    return os << setw(2) << setfill( '0' ) << f; };
```

also no luck.

Any hints?

Comment: You are only passing one parameter to your lambda that needs two parameters. Also you are passing the return value of your lambda to `operator<<` which is an `std::ostream&`.

Answer (score 7):

> I thought the call of the `operator<<` would generate a two-parameter function call.

No, invoking an overloaded `operator<<` is basically the same as invoking a binary function:

```
a << b;
// is equivalent to
operator<<(a, b);
// or to
a.operator<<(b);
```

What you're trying to do is invoke `operator<<` using a lambda that returns an `ostream&` as the right-hand argument, but you're not passing the `ostream&` argument to the lambda itself.

---

`os << w2(os,c.h_)` is syntactically valid, but will not compile because there is no `operator<<(ostream&, ostream&)` definition.

What you can do is simply invoke the lambda without streaming it:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const Clock& c) {
    auto w2 = [](ostream&os, int f) -> ostream& {
        return os << setw(2) << setfill( '0' ) << f; };

    w2(os, c.h_); 
    os <<':'; 
    w2(os, c.m_); 
    os << ':'; 
    return w2(os, c.s_);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RnkylYwJp0pcTCfq)

---

If you want to achieve your desired syntax, you will need a little more work. Here's a possible solution:

```
template <typename TF>
struct streamable : TF
{
    streamable(TF&& f) : TF{std::move(f)} { } 
};

template <typename TF>
auto& operator<<(ostream& os, const streamable<TF>& s)
{
    s(os); return os;
}

template <typename TF>
auto make_streamable_impl(TF f)
{
    return streamable<TF>(std::move(f));
}

template <typename TF>
auto make_streamable(TF f)
{
    return [&](auto&& x) mutable
    { 
        return make_streamable_impl([&](ostream& os) -> auto&
        { 
            f(os, x); 
            return os; 
        });
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const Clock& c) {
    auto w2 = make_streamable([](ostream&os, int f) -> ostream& {
        return os << setw(2) << setfill( '0' ) << f; });
    return os << w2(c.h_) <<':'<<w2(c.m_)<<':'<<w2(c.s_);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OwbI6fU6S9JtwqC3)

Note that a real implementation should probably [**perfectly-capture** the arguments](http://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/capturing_perfectly_forwarded_objects_in_lambdas.html) into the lambdas.

Comment: Of course... Yes I frequently hit that trap with the function-call-ish `<<` use. Thanks, got it. I don't think perfect capture would be required here: We are not in a template, we know exactly what lvalues and rvalues we have. No ref-collapsing needed, as far as I can see.

Comment: @towi: yes, it's not needed here. I was referring to a completely general implementation of `make_streamable`.

Answer (score 2):

This compiles:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const Clock& c) {
    auto w2 = [](ostream&os, int f) -> ostream& {
        return os << setw(2) << setfill( '0' ) << f; };
    return w2( os, c.h_ );
}
```